# Android HttpUrlConnection send multiple parameters with same key

Tags: java, android, api, httpurlconnection

How can i add multiple values with the same name in a HttpUrlConnection request.

example:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("key[]", value1)
params.put("key[]", value2)
```

If i try to add multiple values with the same in postman i works fine, the application will send only one values (depends on request property, [URLConnection setRequestProperty vs addRequestProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458891/urlconnection-setrequestproperty-vs-addrequestproperty)).

I want to add both values as a parameter with the same name

Comment: Even your HashMap will not allow you to add multiple key with same name.

Comment: It's a Hashmap, which doesn't allow two entries with the same key name. It will just overwrite your first entry

Comment: I will change my API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with `Maps` or `HashMaps`.

Taken from Oracles documentation on `Maps`:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

The `put` command will replace the previous value associated with the given `key` in the `map` (you can think of this like an array indexing operation for primitive types).

The Oracle Documentation for `put` states:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replaced.
>
> Returns the previous value associated with key, or null if there was
>   no mapping for key.

This can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29

Comment: I'll change my API, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively You can do this and it will work fine.

You can make a JSONArray like this

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("value1");
array.put("value2");

//and then you can send them as parameter like this-

params.put("key", array.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with `params.put()` But it is possible with `params.add()`

Reference : [Difference between RequestParams add() and put() in AndroidAsyncHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649251/difference-between-requestparams-add-and-put-in-androidasynchttp)